# Do we should use "the" with population?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Which ones we should use:

1. the global population
2. global population

Comment: In many contexts it's a (sometimes "meaningless") stylistic choice. Note that Google Books claims over 6000 written instances of [*with **a** global population*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+a+global+population%22) *[of some specified size, for example]*.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually talk about **the global population**

> The global population is likely to exceed 9 billion within 10 years.

But in some contexts the indefinite article might also be used:

> Earth's resources could not support a global population of more than 10 billion.

It would be correct to omit the article entirely when using such constructions as **global population growth**.

> Global population growth is likely to strain earth's resources within 50 years.

Comment: I'm not convinced there's any significant argument in favour of *specifically* endorsing the "article-less" form when ***global population*** is being used as a "compound attributive noun", modifying some noun such as ***growth***. There's nothing at all wrong with, say, [*with global population approaching*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+global+population+approaching%22) *[however many billions it was approaching when those words were being written]*.

Comment: @Ronald Sole..........                                                                                                my question is that I could not distinguish different between your 2 first examples. Why for the first one you used "the" but for the second one, you did not?